# RESTful way to check availability of usernames, emails, etc

Tags: rest

I've recently gotten very into trying to think as RESTfully as possible, and I'm finding myself stymied by the non-obvious routes.

In this particular case, I'm curious about the RESTful way to check for username and email availability for a user, or anything else that has uniqueness.

My gut tells me that I would want to perform a `GET` on `/users/email` or `/users/username/` each with a required param, or something along the lines of `GET /users/search/` with optional params of `email` and `username`. If you get a `200`, then the `username` or `email` is unavailable; if you get a `404`, then it's available.

I prefer the first option since it's more explicit, but it's not like I've pored over Roy Fielding's thesis to know well enough what to do.

What's the most sound approach here?

Answer (score 8):

The first approach does seem to be more "RESTful". You try to GET a specific resource (by username or email) and get it if it exists or get a status message "unavailable resource". This would be:

- GET /users/username/johnwayne (to "get" johnwayne resource/username availability...)

This should generate:

- 200: if resource exists
- 404: if the resource does not exist

The second one seems more like "SOAP"-like web service, where you define a "function" (/users/search/) with some "parameters" (username, email)...

Comment: I changed them because if the resource exists, it's unavailable. If it does not exist, it's available.

Comment: sorry (will edit my answer)... I did not "read" in that way, you mean it returns "200" if the username is available... I understand, but it is a bit confusing according to the semantics of the GET resource. Maybe you should consider to handle that in the client, i.e., in the client you check if the resource is unavailable you can crete it (username is available)... But this is my interpretation, I do think there is quite a lot of room for interpretation :)

Answer (score 1):

For unique fields, first option is a good fit (/users/email or /users/username/), for non-unique fields search would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

i would recommend, you use HEAD request instead of GET.

Using a GET may pose a security problem. A hacker can use a combination to identify valid username as GET would either result in 200 or 404.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to get a list of users with your mail by

```
GET /users?query=asd@gmail.com
```

And here you can find 1 item or 0 items. In first case the address isn't unique. In another - it's unique